# Selenium - Edit Code using a userinterface

Tags: python, selenium, interface

So i automated the task of login into a discordserver and posting a text using Selenium. All works fine but my goal is to make an inputbox for the email and password. The user inputs the information and presses save and the password and mail is supposed to write itsself into the code and save.

What are the best approaches for this? I'm still pretty new to python so go easy on me.

```js
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

url = "https://discordapp.com/channels/530588470905929729/538868623981412362"
driver.get(url)
email = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='email']")))
email.send_keys("Mail@mail.com")

password = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//input[@type='password']")))
password.send_keys("Password" + Keys.ENTER)

sleep(5)

textbox = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//textarea[@placeholder='Message #bot-commands']")))
textbox.send_keys("!work" + Keys.ENTER)

sleep(30)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Use pymsgbox and store

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are those libraries?

Comment: https://pymsgbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html
Use prompt and store in a config file

Comment: So something like `password.send_keys(pymsgbox.password('Enter your password.') + Keys.ENTER)` ? or where does the input get returned to? How do i  overwrite the file tho?

Comment: Get the password and store it once; next time read from the file

Comment: will the script run on 1 or many system?

Comment: im planning on givin it to friends

Comment: then y u want to overwrite the file ?

Comment: because the programm will run every 3 hours and if they have to constantly input everything itll get annoying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195396/discussion-between-smartmanoj-and-itsolidude).